# Autohotkey remapping Alt Gr to Win Modifyer

Tags: autohotkey, windows-key

I am trying to build a very simple AutoHotkey script but it doesnt seem to be working. I've bought a keyboard with no Win key and no programable hardware layer so I am planning on using AHK to remap the Alt Gr key to the Windows key.

Can anypoint give me pointers to where I am going wrong.

```
<^>!l::
MsgBox Win L pressed.
return

<^>!r::
Send {# down}
Send {r down}
Send {# up}
Send {# up}
return

<^>!e::
SendInput #&e
return
```

Comment: I suggest you try the following line:  ralt::lwin

Answer (score 0):

Using your middle example, it'd be like so:

```
<^>!r::
SendInput, {LWin Down}r{LWin Up}
Return
```

You can use RWin or LWin per your preference since it really shouldn't matter at the software level.